# Combine 2 tables with 2 common fields into 1 table with the 2 fields and a source indicator

Tags: ms-access

this is my first time posting so forgive any errors please :)

Source File: Fields

Table 1: ID, Client Number

Table 2: ID, Client Number

Table 1 shows the Customer, and table 2 shows the Bill Payer.Both tables use ID as the transaction ID. So one transaction has 1 record in table 1, and 1 in table 2.

Desired Output:

Table 3: ID, Client Number, Customer/Payer.

I am aware that i can do to append table queries to 1 destination table to achieve but if i can do this with ONE SELECT query that would make the "flow" of my database alot smoother, as i am replacing an old query. Any help would be appreciated and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Client_Number, 'Customer' AS Type FROM Table 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Client_Number, 'Payer' AS Type FROM Table 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, ClientNumber, 'Customer' as Kind FROM Customer
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, ClientNumber, 'Player' as Kind FROM Player
```